# Having a TCP connection behind a URL with a path Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, tcp

I want to have an HTTP server which allows me to establish a TCP connection with a remote computer whenever I specify a given path inside the URL in a browser.

For example... let's say that I have a computer with a public IP address and a hostname as the server (mydomain.com:9000) and a remote computer with a local IP address (192.168.0.1) connected to the server. Somehow I want to establish a TCP connection between a client and the remote computer. And to make it easier just enter an URL with a path (mydomain.com:9000/remote). NOT WITH ANOTHER PORT! Also, I want the connection to be done if and only if that path is entered.

To illustrate a little better how the system works:

```
      _________                       _________                       _________
      |       |       internet        |       |     local network     |       |
      |_______|      ---------->      |_______|      ---------->      |_______|
      ____|____      <----------      ____|____      <----------      ____|____
        client                          server                      remote computer
   sends http request                checks path                   gets http request
mydomain.com:9000/remote      establishes TCP connection            handles request
```

I made some code with node js to make sure that the connection was possible. And it is, now I only have to be able to check the path and establish the connection only then. My code is a simple TCP tunneling proxy and it works fine. But when I try to implement the path it doesn't.

```
//Import modules
const net = require('net');
const http = require('http');

let inpath = false;

// Create proxy server
const proxy = http.createServer( function(req,res){
    console.log(req.url);

    //Check path
    if(req.url == '/remote')
        inpath = true;
});

proxy.on('connection', client => {

    if(inpath)
    {
        const remote = new net.Socket();

        //Establish connection
        remote.connect(80,'192.168.0.100');

        client.on('error', err => {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
            proxy.close();
        });
        
        //Port-forwarding
        client.pipe(remote);
        remote.pipe(client);
    }
});
proxy.listen(9000);
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you'll find that the `connection` event is firing well before your request handler callback is being called.  This is because a TCP connection (for which the `connection` event is triggered) occurs from a client connecting before the client makes its HTTP request.  Additionally, what you have isn't really going to work reliably because HTTP keep-alive may mean that multiple requests will come down a single TCP connection.

To fix this, you need to move all of that code you have in your `connection` event up to your HTTP request handler.

You'll run into other problems though, in that now your code is effectively handling the HTTP request/response, so you'll need to parse and rebuild the request/response data when communicating with the upstream server.

If you truly do wish to handle this at the TCP level, don't use `http.createServer()`.  Use `net` instead and create a normal TCP server.  Then, parse the request data yourself and if you find the certain path you want in the request, make the proxying TCP connection, and be sure to send down the existing buffers so that the upstream server can get the full HTTP request.

Comment: Thanks! Very helpful! The only problem I came by using `net` instead of `http` is that I do not know how to parse the request data from the socket and get the path form it.
Do you know a way of doing this?

Comment: @Didash You would have to make your own HTTP parser.  In all honesty though, since all you need is the path, I would probably just split on lines, then split the top line.  There are a lot of weird edge cases with HTTP requests, but you don't need to concern yourself with those since you just need the path.

Comment: Thank you very much! You really helped me out here. Very concrete answers. Just what I needed.